# Python: How to Draw heatmap on a image with X, Y coordinates with temperature

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a layout image and trying to draw heatmap on it. Basically I have three columns, 1. x coordinate, 2. y coordinate, 3. Temperature.

Ex data:

```
[x, y, temp]
[0, 0, 28'c,
3, 4, 36'c,
8, 10, 38'c]
```

I want to generate a heat map for temperature pattern analysis and overlap on my layout on given x,y coordinates. Sample image as below

[image: Sample image link]

Comment: Have a look at tricontour.  But questions usually require a little more effort than this to be acceptable.

Comment: @Nishanth, did you find a solution? I am facing the same issue now, thanks